# Model Popup extender not working

Tags: asp.net, mysql, ajax

I am working on a project and  i want to popup a panel on a click of a button but its not working what could be the reason behind ..as i tried after updating the ajax toolkit again its not working.

Please give me a solution for that. Here is what I have tried:

```
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
     <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
     <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopupisbn" runat="server" style="display:none" />
     <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopupisbn" PopupControlID="pnl_isbn" CancelControlID="btnCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlpopup"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
     <asp:Panel ID="pnl_isbn" runat="server" Visible="False" width="400px"CssClass="color">
     <asp:Label ID="lbl_isbn" runat="server" Text="ISBN " ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txt_isbn" runat="server" ValidationGroup="b" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:Label ID="lbl_booktwoid" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="booktwoid" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
     <asp:Label ID="lbl_conditionisbn" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Condition"></asp:Label>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_con" runat="server" Width="120px" ValidationGroup="b"></asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:Button ID="btn_isbnnumber" runat="server" Text="Add ISBN" CssClass="blue button" ValidationGroup="b"/></asp:Panel>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"/> 
</form>
```

cs code on button click:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnl_isbn.Visible = true;
    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();

}
```

Comment: btnShowPopupisbn where its

Comment: why  display:none in btnShowPopupisbn?

Comment: yor button display is null so from where you calling show popup

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a closing quote PopupControlID="pnl_isbn".Please check it out.